# Gradle + hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, gradle

I have Java application with DB. For building i use Gradle.
How i can define `user_name/password/server` for tests in my application by command line during building.

Also I have `hibernate.cfg.xml` file and if I configure it manually - everything works fine. But I need to configure it by command line.

Line from hibernate:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">${myDbUser}</property>
```

I have tried to use command line:

```
 gradle -PmyDbUser=my_value build
```

And

```
 gradle -Phibernate.connection.username=my_value build
```

--- no effect.
In logs I see next: Cannon access with ''@'db.local'.
So in the summary Gradle don't see my variables in `hibernate.cfg.xml`.

Can somebody help me? It will be great, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you need those values as system properties, use `-Dkey=value` as usual for Java programs. `-P key=value` sets Gradle project properties that you can use in your build scripts. You can of course also use Gradle project properties to replace some placeholders in some texts or to set some system property when running some application from the Gradle build.

Comment: Yes, i know it, and I have tried to use key -D but it isn't work and I don't where is error. It looks like Gradle don't see my strings in hibernate.cfg.xml

Comment: Well, I'd say Gradle doesn't care what is written in hibernate.cfg.xml, why should it? What do you expect to happen when you do what?

Comment: i expect that for my variables in hibernate.cfg.xml will use my strings which i define by command line

Comment: how I can tell Gradle to provide my variables for Hibernate.cfg.xml?

Comment: Who? As I said, Gradle doesn't care about content of hibernate.cfg.xml, Gradle doesn't use hibernate. If you want Gradle e. g. to replace the variable in hibernate.cfg.xml with the project properties on packaging your application, you have to tell it so. But you provided way too less information to give concrete advice. And each answer of you misses half the words. You should start writing correct english sentences if you want to keep posting on SO.

Comment: Sorry for my English, it isn't my native language. So, i need to use credentials only during building/testing, not generate hibernate.xml.cfg with correct variables. Which information i need provide for resolving my problem?

Comment: Neither is it mine. :-)